# riot js ternary for conditional onClick event

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I want to conditionally assign an event handler in a riot tag... so I tried the below:

```
<ul>
    <li class="email__ {active--: showEmail} {disabled--: !hasEmailMsg}"
        onClick={hasEmailMsg: handlePreviewChange('email')}
    ></li>
    <li class="mobile__ {active--: showMobile} {disabled--: !hasMobileMsg}"
        onClick={hasMobileMsg: handlePreviewChange('mobile')}
    ></li>
</ul>
```

But it thinks that `hasEmailMsg` / `hasMobileMsg` are the callback functions... any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used Riot.js, but it doesn't look like you're using the ordinary JavaScript ternary syntax. Have you tried a syntax like:

```
<li class="email__ {active--: showEmail} {disabled--: !hasEmailMsg}"
        onClick={hasEmailMsg ? handlePreviewChange('email') : doNothing }
></li>
```

where `doNothing` is just a function that.. does nothing. (Assuming that's the behaviour you want).

I'm not familiar with your exact setup, but I tried doing a **short demo using JSFiddle** here: https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/hfu52x0s/ where I got the ternary funcitonality to work. You probably have a better chance than I to see the parallels to your code.

Comment: interestingly, evaluating the ternary in any form does not work with `onClick`.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to JSFiddle where I got the ternary operator to work in slightly different scenario. Let me know if it's helpful or not. @daino3